# NgInputTags autocomplete is not showing my results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

Hello I am working with ng-input-tags below is my html code:

```
<tags-input on-tag-removed="removeTag(modaltask,$tag)" id="modaltask-tags-{{modaltask.id}}" display-property="tag" class="form-control" ng-model="modaltask.tags">
  <auto-complete source="getAvailableTag($query)" min-length="0" load-on-focus="true" load-on-empty="true" max-results-to-show="32" ></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

When I click inside the input I am getting a console errorTypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.  my controller file looks like this

```
$scope.getAvailableTag = function($query){
    MyTasksService.getAvailableTags($query).then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
    },function(reject){});
}
```

And my service js file

```
this.getAvailableTags = function(value) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(THE URL...).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.availableTags);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        ErrorService.raiseError(data, status);
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The api call works properly and is returning data. in the format

```
availableTag: {
  {
    id: 1,
    tag: test
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getAvailableTag` must return a value to feed to autocomplete, that can be either an array or a promise:

```
$scope.getAvailableTag = function($query){
    return MyTasksService.getAvailableTags($query).then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
        return response; // This is important!
    },function(reject){});
}
```

You can find more information about the autocomplete directive on [this page](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted).